# SerializedMethodField vs overriding save() method : What is the best choice to deal with calculated fields in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I develop a django app with a lot of calculated properties for business logic. For example, let us take model Task, that is just an ordinary task for students. It is necessary to obtain the number of users that likes this task, that solved it, attempted to solve it, etc

Now I am using to approaches to this challenge. The first is to use SerializedMethodField

```
solved_users_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_solved_users_number')

 def get_solved_users_number(self, object):
     #business logic
     return 42
```

The second is to provide a field in the model I use and update it every time the model changes. Overriden save() method suits for such purposes.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.solved_users_number = 0
        else:
            self.solved_users_number += 1

        return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What is the best choice to deal with calculated fields in django?

I tried both and still not sure